# Custom graphical device in Sweave

Tags: r, pdf, graphics, utf-8, sweave

My [problem of inserting a pdf graphic with a special character in a Sweave document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075826/export-plot-as-pdf-with-a-utf8-character) has been solved by creating the pdf plot outside Sweave itself and then importing it.

Following the Sweave documentation, I have written a custom graphical device which should construct the pdf graphic exactly in the same way. However it doesn't work. Can you explain me why the second graphic of the Sweave document below does not work whereas it should be created exactly as the first one ? Am I wrong to believe it should ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<setup, echo=FALSE>>=
mycairo <- function(name, width = 7, height = 7, ...) { 
  grDevices::cairo_pdf(name, width = width, height = height)
}
mycairo.off <- function() {
    cat("shutting down mycairo\n")
    invisible(grDevices::dev.off())
}
@

\section{Export plot}

<<Export_plot, echo=FALSE>>=
cairo_pdf("exported_plot.pdf")
par(mar=c(6,7,0,6))
ylab <- expression(paste("", bar(italic("\u2113")), "(",phi[0], "|", italic(list(x,y)), ")"))
plot(0,0, ylab=ylab, xlab=NA, cex.lab=3)
invisible(dev.off())
@

% insert exported plot 
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{exported_plot.pdf}


\section{Direct plot}

<<mycairo_plot, echo=FALSE,  fig=TRUE, pdf=TRUE, grdevice=mycairo, width=4, height=4>>=
par(mar=c(6,6,0,6))
ylab <- expression(paste("", bar(italic("\u2113")), "(",phi[0], "|", italic(list(x,y)), ")"))
plot(0,0, ylab=ylab, xlab=NA, cex.lab=1)
@


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: change `mycairo` to `grDevices::cairo_pdf(paste(name, "pdf", sep = "."), width = width, height = height)`. Ive not done this before but [`my.Swd` from here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/RweaveLatex.html) appears to do this

Comment: @user20650 Yes it works !! Feel free to convert your comment to an answer so that I'l accept it.

Comment: Good stuff, Stephane -  please write it up... youve done the hard work writing a good question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@user20650 kindly proposed me to convert the answer given in his/her comment to an official one.

It suffices to include the `pdf` file extension in the `cairo_pdf` function. Then replace the `mycairo` function with:

```
mycairo <- function(name, width = 7, height = 7, ...) { 
  grDevices::cairo_pdf(sprintf("%s.pdf", name), width = width, height = height)
}
```

As a side note, instead of specifying `grdevice=mycairo` in each figure chunk, you can also set it as a global option:

```
\SweaveOpts{grdevice=mycairo}
```